# PostgreSQL Separate Columns based on value containing alpha or not

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with values like: 123, 123A, 123B, 123C, etc..  I am creating a view and need to separate this column into two based on whether or not the value contains a letter.

EX:

Primary (Column 1)
123

Secondary (Column 2)
123A,
123B,
123C,
...

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include table definition (ddl scripts), sample data as in the table, the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**.  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.